# Auth0 with IdentityServer4 multi-application SSO not working

Tags: .net, .net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4, auth0

I have followed below article and configured Auth0 as external IDP.
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html

All working fine for single application login, and when i open second application in same browser it get session for second application's login (as auht0 cookie for user extists), but issue is i get logout from first application.

SessionId getting changed for both application for same user.

I need a same sessionId between application, is it possible with external IDP?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good morning PradipB, while this question seems more related to IdentityServer4, I am going to share our Auth0 documentation on SSO that details how Single Sign On works from our side of things. Please let me know if you have any questions. https://auth0.com/docs/sso/current

Answer (score 0):

Get idea how it works, to make Auth0 SSO works with IdentityServer4. 
For each AddOpenIdConnect We have to keep `CallbackPath` Identical. And IDS will treat each unique `CallbackPath` as different client for SSO.

> To make it work I have created one login app in Auth0 and configured
>   this one app with `AddOpenIdConnect` only. All other application's id
>   (which is created in Auht0 for each portal of our platform) is passed
>   to auht0 for rule execution using querystring.

[image]